# android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar requires API level 21 (current min is 8)

Tags: android, api

today i'm choose the Theme Material in the styles.xml but it says:

> `android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar` requires API level 21 (current min is 8)

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
```

What can I do for fix this problem?
PS: I don't know but i don't have a package: values-v21

Comment: Are you using eclipse or android studio

Comment: @Ayoub Please stop using [code snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for Java code. They are for [Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/245062/11683).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` instead of `android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar`. This is caused because of Android versions before 5.0 doesn't support Material Theme natively and AppCompat must be used if you are developing for Android versions below 5.0